# toolbar button to upload to Netsuite? (in Aptana Studio 3)

Tags: aptana, aptana3, netsuite

I have Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.9.201202141038

I'm using it to edit some Netsuite client scripts (javascript).  The netsuite plugin lets me upload scripts to netsuite, which is great, but I have to right click on the filename in the project explorer, pick "Netsuite" and then "Upload"... too many clicks.

What I want is one button to stick on the toolbar that will do the upload.  Is this customization possible?  Not that I'm lazy but when debugging it becomes a pain to do so much right-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse/Aptana, the "Project Explorer" can do this. If you select a project and/or file within that project, the "Upload" buttons are made available IF you have set up a remote connection to that project.

I am not certain if your uploads/pushes to Netsuite are via FTP but, if they are, just add your remote connection to the project. To do this, expand your project folder the project in the Project Explorer view and then right-click on the Connections icon to add a new (FTP) connection.Once this is setup, any file selected in the Project Explorer can be uploaded with a simply button click from this view.

Not sure if that is exactly what you want but, in the meantime, might get you closer to it!

Comment: It's not ftp - I can't see exactly what's doing but I would guess it's using the web services interface.  As I said, I am currently using the upload option in the project explorer.  There are no connections listed in the connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

Hit ctrl+shift+; and the file will save and upload.